# Hex to int32-Value

Tags: lua, int32

I'm currently trying to convert a hex string into its value as a signed int.

Example:

```
0000000E - 14
FFFFFFF2 - -14
```

So: converting the value for unsigned values is easy:

```
print(tonumber("0000000E", 16)) // outputs 14
```

negative values can be parsed like this:

```
num = tonumber("FFFFFFF2", 16)
print(4294967296 - num - num)
```

but unfortunatly, I need to detect, whether the MSB is set for this to work. 
This would be easy, if my lua implementation would support the Bit-Library, but unfortunatly that isn't the case.

So: How can I convert signed hex-integers into a LUA number?

Comment: What stops you from just checking if most significant byte from original hex string is in `8-F` range?

Comment: Or checking whether the unsigned value is greater than 2^31-1.

Comment: To get signed number: `num = (tonumber("FFFFFFF2", 16)+2^31)%2^32-2^31`.  Now just check if `num < 0`

Answer (score 2):

The best answer is probably by Egor from comments:

```
num = (tonumber("FFFFFFF2", 16) + 2^31) % 2^32 - 2^31
```